# How to make Sony Vegas Pro 13 work on a 4K display

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro, 4k

I bought Sony Vegas Pro 13 recently for my 4K laptop, but when I fired it up, the loading screen did not look good. The text was running into itself, and it didn't fit in the window.

[image: mangled loading screen]

When the application loaded, the buttons and strips on the editor were only about 5mm tall.

[image: Vegas main window with shrunken buttons and strips]

Is there a way to make Vegas work on a 4K screen? Are there settings I can change, or a patch I can install? And if not, is there something in the works for this? I will add that I did try changing the screen resolution, but it still looks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's apparently a hack which alters the Vegas executable to solve this problem. There's a setting of `dpiAware` in the application manifest which falsely tells Windows that Vegas is DPI aware and will scale up text and icons on a HiDPI display. Vegas does not do this. So, the value should be changed from true to false.

The hack tutorial alongwith link to required tool is available at `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vvr0c5VHGIM`

I haven't needed to do this so I can't vouch for the method but it appears to work.

Comment: I could not get this solution to work recently. I've been just suffering and losing my eyesight. @XamuelSchulman Did you do something specific to get this solution to work?

Comment: @fredsbend Not really. I just followed what the tutorial told me to do and then after a restart it worked.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman Well, I'll try again, maybe. Thanks.

Comment: Nearly two years later, I did get this to work, but this video link is dead. Looks like this one is the same thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vvr0c5VHGIM